Powershell update object property value not as expect
I have one Json file and I just want to update some specified property value instead of all the same value in the json file.
But the current situation is that I can replace the specified attribute value, but it will have an additional structure.
My test Json file like:
{
    "$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
    "resources":  [
                      {
                          "apiVersion":  "2016-06-01",
                          "kind":  "V2",
                          "properties":  {
                                             "displayName":  "azuredatafactory",
                                             "overallStatus":  "Ready",
                                             "connectionState":  "Enabled",
                                             "customParameterValues":  {
                                                                       },
                                             "alternativeParameterValues":  {
                                                                            },
                                             "parameterValueType":  "Alternative",
                                             "createdTime":  "2024-06-27T09:03:39.9477Z",
                                             "changedTime":  "2024-06-27T09:03:39.9477Z",
                                             "testLinks":  [

                                                           ],
                                             "connectionRuntimeUrl":  "https://89ad7e55624ad1be.08.common.logic-eastasia.azure-apihub.net/apim/azuredatafactory/9fed9f23xxxxxa34f23d186b"
                                         },
                          "id":  "/subscriptions/e1c6546xxxxx218a/resourceGroups/rxxxxxl-ietl01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuredatafactory",
                          "name":  "azuredatafactory",
                          "type":  "Microsoft.Web/connections",
                          "location":  "eastasia",
                          "tags":  {
                                       "CreatedOnDate":  "2024-06-27T09:03:39.3814086Z",
                                       "Environment":  "D"
                                   }
                      }
                  ]
}

I just want to update the "displayName":  "azuredatafactory" under the node resources.properties and the "name":  "azuredatafactory" under the node resources.
My test powershell scripts like below:
$RevertTypeForJson = Get-Content -Path "<pathtoMyJsonfiles>\MyTestJson.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$RevertTypeForJson.resources | ForEach-Object {
    $_.name = @($_.name -replace "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)", "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)_NewValue")
    $_.properties.displayName = @($_.properties.displayName -replace "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)", "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)_NewValue")
}

$NewRevertTypeForJson = $RevertTypeForJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Write-Host "$NewRevertTypeForJson"

However, the output given is:
                       "properties":  {
                                          "displayName":  [
                                                              "azuredatafactory_NewVlaue"

                                                          ],

and
                   "name":  [
                                "azuredatafactory_SIT"
                            ],

Instead of "displayName": "azuredatafactory_NewVlaue", and "name":  "azuredatafactory_NewVlaue",
How to update my scripts to achieve the expect result "displayName": "azuredatafactory_NewVlaue", and "name":  "azuredatafactory_NewVlaue",?
Note: I cannot replace with global variables. I know it would be simple, but you can see that the ID value also contains the same value, which cannot be changed, so I must modify the value under specific properties.

That's because you're explicitly requesting the creation of an array with @(...). Remove @( and ) and it'll work

@MathiasR.Jessen, Wow, you're right. Thank you very much. I'm not very familiar with Powershell, so many times I'm not clear about specific syntax. Thank you for your comment. If you're willing, you can convert your comment into an answer, and I'm happy to mark it as an answer

PowerShell is generally pretty flexible when it comes to output typing - if a pipeline outputs 0 objects, any assignment target will receive $null, with exactly 1 object you get just that 1 object, and with 2 or more PowerShell will wrap the output in an array.
This works out well most of the time, but sometimes you want an array, regardless of the number of objects a particular pipeline or expression evaluates to.
Enter the array subexpression operator @(...)
@(...) will cause PowerShell to always wrap the concatenated output from any and all top-level statements nested inside it in an array, which is why you get the additional [...] around the value in the final JSON - [...] is the JSON notation for an array.
Remove the @(...)'s and it'll work as expected:
$RevertTypeForJson.resources | ForEach-Object {
    $_.name = $_.name -replace "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)", "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)_NewValue"
    $_.properties.displayName = $_.properties.displayName -replace "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)", "$(VariableForAzuredatafactory)_NewValue"
}


Thanks. BTW, Now, I found that I still need do same update for the ID id":  "/subscriptions/e1c6546xxxxx218a/resourceGroups/rxxxxxl-ietl01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuredatafactory"". But when I use the scripts $_.id = $_.id -replace "$_.id", "$_.id_NewValue", it not work, would you please help me?

@Joy You don't need the -replace operator at all: $_.id += "_NewValue"

Got it, thanks a lot.
